# how to put into list comprehension

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

How can I put following syntax into list comprehension:

`matching_withkeyWords` and `keyWords` are list.

```
 for i in matching_withkeyWords:
     for k in keyWords:
         if k in i:
             for j in i:
                 print(k, j, cosdis(word2vec(k), word2vec(j)))
```

Comment: You aren't building a list, so you wouldn't use a list comprehension at all.

Comment: Do you want to make a list of everything you're printing?

Comment: @chepner- No I was not, I was trying to bring in line to feed that result into a dictionary.  Why do you advise so? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
list_to_print = [[(k, j, cosdis(word2vec(k), word2vec(j))) for j in i for k in keyWords if k in i] for i in matching_withkeyWords]
print(list_to_print)
```